# Using Openlayers proxy.cgi with Fedora?

Tags: python, proxy, cgi, fedora, geoserver

I am trying to move my application into Fedora server from my Windows server. My problem is that I use proxy.cgi to get information from geoserver.
How should I edit proxy.cgi after I move it into Fedora?

I have tried

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and it still only return plain text.

This is my proxy.cgi code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

"""This is a blind proxy that we use to get around browser
restrictions that prevent the Javascript from loading pages not on the
same server as the Javascript.  This has several problems: it's less
efficient, it might break some sites, and it's a security risk because
people can use this proxy to browse the web and possibly do bad stuff
with it.  It only loads pages via http and https, but it can load any
content type. It supports GET and POST requests."""

import urllib2
import cgi
import sys, os

# Designed to prevent Open Proxy type stuff.

allowedHosts = ['www.google.co.id','www.openlayers.org', 'openlayers.org', 
                'labs.metacarta.com', 'world.freemap.in', 
                'prototype.openmnnd.org', 'geo.openplans.org',
                'sigma.openplans.org', 'demo.opengeo.org',
                'www.openstreetmap.org', 'sample.azavea.com',
                'v2.suite.opengeo.org', 'v-swe.uni-muenster.de:8080', 
                'vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org', 'www.openrouteservice.org', '172.20.32.11:8080', '172.20.32.11','localhost', 

'localhost:8080', 
                'http://192.168.64.2:8080', 'http://192.168.64.2']

method = os.environ["REQUEST_METHOD"]

if method == "POST":
    qs = os.environ["QUERY_STRING"]
    d = cgi.parse_qs(qs)
    if d.has_key("url"):
        url = d["url"][0]
    else:
        url = "http://www.openlayers.org"
else:
    fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
    url = fs.getvalue('url', "http://www.openlayers.org")

try:
    host = url.split("/")[2]
    if allowedHosts and not host in allowedHosts:
        print "Status: 502 Bad Gateway"
        print "Content-Type: text/plain"
        print
        print "This proxy does not allow you to access that location (%s)." % (host,)
        print
        print os.environ

    elif url.startswith("http://") or url.startswith("https://"):

        if method == "POST":
            length = int(os.environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"])
            headers = {"Content-Type": os.environ["CONTENT_TYPE"]}
            body = sys.stdin.read(length)
            r = urllib2.Request(url, body, headers)
            y = urllib2.urlopen(r)
        else:
            y = urllib2.urlopen(url)

        # print content type header
        i = y.info()
        if i.has_key("Content-Type"):
            print "Content-Type: %s" % (i["Content-Type"])
        else:
            print "Content-Type: text/plain"
        print

        print y.read()

        y.close()
    else:
        print "Content-Type: text/plain"
        print
        print "Illegal request."

except Exception, E:
    print "Status: 500 Unexpected Error"
    print "Content-Type: text/plain"
    print 
    print "Some unexpected error occurred. Error text was:", E
```

Comment: Does "print os.environ" represent a security hole by leaking environment variables to one and all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webserver needs to be setup to execute `.cgi` scripts.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html

Example (*Apache*:);

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/
```

I should also point out that CGI is not really the recommend approach in Python. Please consider one of the following:

- WSGI (http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- A Web Framework (*there are many to choose from*)

As noted by the OP's comments below (*no sudo/root access to the server*)
your only other option is to build a simple web app with a suitable web framework
and wrap the CGI using something like [wsgi2cgi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsgi2cgi)

Here is an example using [circuits.web](http://circuitsweb.com)

hello.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Contnt-Type: text/html"
print
print "Hello World!"
```

cgiwrapper.py (*server*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from wsgi2cgi import CGI

from circuits.web import Server
from circuits.web.wsgi import Gateway


def app(environ, start_response):
    wrapper = CGI("hello.cgi")
    return wrapper.application(environ, start_response)


server = Server(("0.0.0.0", 5000))
Gateway({"/": app}).register(server)
server.run()
```

example output:

```
$ curl -q -o - http://localhost:5000/
Hello World!
```

This would not require root/sudo access to the server; *but you are restricted to running on non-priveleged ports* (>1024).

Comment: hello james i dont have the root authority is your options can be implemented without root users?

Comment: Sorry no such luck. You'll have to contact your system administrators. I'm afraid you won't be able to solve this problem without root/sudo privileges to the system (*easily*) Your only other option is ``wsgi2cgi``.

Comment: okay thank you, one more, how can i setup the webserver to execute .cgi scripts? (if i have root privileges)

Comment: See Updated response above.

Comment: yes maybe i can use this, my geoserver is using port 8080. James can you help me edit my proxy.cgi scripts? i really don't understand how to code python.

Comment: If your ``proxy.cgi`` worked on Windows before as you claimed it should work with the **generic** solution I presented above. I used this as a quick prototype to wrap the mapserver cgi a while ago.

Comment: hi james i have been able to run the script but i got error Some unexpected error occurred. Error text was: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out> why is that?

Comment: Not sure without seeing some kind of traceback or error. 110 Connection Timed Out coudl mean anything